# Flask, How to refresh an ajax url with a generated id

Tags: javascript, ajax, flask

I am new in javascript, I have created a flask site and I would like to follow ansible tower job.
I have create a specific route :

```py
@app.route("/tower/<int:id>", methods=['POST','GET'])
def status(id):
    launch = True
    job_info = {}
    status = refreshstatus(id)
    return render_template(
        'tower.html',
        job_info = job_info,
        status = status,
        launch = launch,
        id = id)

@app.route("/tower", methods=['POST','GET'])
def tower():
    launch = False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        keyword = request.form['launchjob']
        logger.info("Test | Keyword var => " + keyword)
        template_id = request.form['template_id']
        job_info = launch_job(template_id, keyword)
        launch = True
        return render_template('tower.html', job_info = job_info, launch = launch)
    else:
        return render_template('tower.html')
```

my js script:

```
function refresh() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/tower/' + id,
        dataType: 'json',
        id: { id : job_info.job_id },
        success: function(data) {
        $('#statustable').html(data);
        }
      });
      setTimeout(refresh, 10000);
      console.log('refresh')
    };
$(function(){
      refresh();
});
```

and my html file

```
<th scope="row"></th>
<td> {{ job_info.job_id }}</td>
<td><p class="text-warning" id="statustable">{{ job_info.job_status }}</p></td>
<td><a href="{{ job_info.url }}" target="_blank">Lien vers le stdout</a></td>
```

When I refresh manually it works the job status changes, but no auto refresh.
Could you help ?

Thanks

David

Comment: There do the variables `id` and `job_info.job_id` in your JavaScript come from?

Comment: `job_info.job_id` come from a python function `tower` => `job_info = launch_job(template_id, keyword)`, it's a dictionnary. And the id is declared in the javascript : `id: { id : job_info.job_id }`

Comment: No, it isn't. JavaScript runs in the browser, Python runs on the server. They can't see each other's variables. So my guess would be that in your browser's console there are a couple of "variable undefined" errors.

Comment: Yes you're right, I saw variable undefined, but how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript can't see your server's variables. `job_info.job_id` will not be defined in your browser.

You need to transport the variable value to the browser somehow if you want to use it there.

- One way would be to read the text from the `<td>{{ job_info.job_id }}</td>`.
- A nicer way would be to use an [HTML data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

If you change your view like this on the server side:

```
<tr data-job-id="{{job_info.job_id|tojson|forceescape}}">
  <th scope="row"></th>
  <td>{{ job_info.job_id }}</td>
  <td><p class="text-warning" id="statustable">{{ job_info.job_status }}</p></td>
  <td><a href="{{ job_info.url }}" target="_blank">Lien vers le stdout</a></td>
</tr>
```

Then you can access the value from `data-job-id="..."` with jQuery on the client side:

```
function refresh() {
    const id = $('#statustable').closest("tr").data('job-id');
    $('#statustable').load('/tower/' + id);
    setTimeout(refresh, 10000);
};

$(refresh);
```

- Together with [Jinja's `tojson` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.tojson), data attributes allow you to transport complex data like the complete `job_info` structure to your client, not just simple values like a single ID. Caveat: Remember to use the `forceescape` filter to avoid [issues](https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/1002).
- Move `data-job-id="..."` to an element in your HTML where it makes the most sense.
- `$(element).load(url)` is the short form of `$.ajax(url)` -> `success` -> `$(element).html(response)`. See https://api.jquery.com/load/.
- `$(refresh)` is the short form of `$(function () { refresh(); })`. See https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery3.

Comment: It works, I have some design to do but the js is working. Thank you for your time, I will look to data attribute it's interesting!